# Setup load balancer for Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: wordpress, cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm new to google compute engine and have installed Wordpress on compute engine using gogole cloud launcher.Now I want to setup load balancer for that,
Here's what I have tried:
Step by step:

1. Install WP using cloud launcher which create a vm instance.
2. I have create a new VM instance
3. Create a Instance template
4. Create an Instance group
5. Then I setup a health check
6. Create a firewall rule with which permits HTTP & HTTPs traffic at 130.211.0.0/22
7. Then I create a load balancer in which creates Backend service, for host and path rules I leave it blank and setup fronted service.

But my load balancer is not working, when I try to open my Wordpress site from load balancer IP it says : **Server Error , it's temporary not process your request try again later after 30 seconds**.

Help me please!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you share how you setup the frontend service?  Are these the instructions you followed?  https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto

Comment: One thing which has confused me is , do I need to create same VM instances  with Wordpress installation to include in Instance group for load balancing?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create firewall rule. These are the steps I followed to create my setup:

1. Deploy a Google click to deploy Wordpress package using the cloud launcher
2. Create an image using this deployment
3. Create an instance template using the image
4. Create an instance group using the instance template

Make sure you create a health checkup in the instance group, otherwise the autohealing doesn't work. Also make sure the instance group accepts http/https traffic by checking the boxes.

Once this is done create an Http load balancer. Include the instance group in the backend service. Host and path leave it as it. Create a frontend. Create loadbalancer.

Do not delete/stop the initial Wordpress deployment that you used to create the image, otherwise your site will not work.